# Change maximum request length in asp.net mvc without modifying web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As the question suggest is it possible to change the maximum request length in an asp.net mvc project without modifying the web.config file?

The project is on several client servers which I don't want to have to manually change for each one so hoping I can put something in global.asax to write it instead or similar?

EDIT:
OR is it possible to add another config file with just the settings I want to overwrite?

Comment: Try to use this property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Any idea what the configSection object relates to?

Comment: Also says its read only

Comment: Do you mean machine.config?

Comment: No I mean web.config.  Basically I want to override the maximum request length from the application and not have to modify either the web.config, iis or machine.config as requires changes on each client.

Comment: Sorry, that was meant as a hint towards the _"is it possible to add another config file"_. You can set machine-wide settings in machine.config

Comment: I was thinking more of a second web.config with just the settings I want to overwrite but I think that still needs a change to the original web.config file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, as the web  config stores the configuration values that your application uses to define how it behaves - in this case, the length of the data you require to be passed on.

```
You would need to modify the web.config as follows:


<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And if you are on IIS7 above, the following needs to be configured as well:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Additional Note: **maxAllowedContentLength** is measured in bytes while **maxRequestLength** is measured in kilobytes

Some options you have are:

1. Powershell script that would read your web.config files on the different servers and update the configuration values accordingly.
2. Uploading the web config directly via FTP or publish.
3. Modifying the web config directlyon the server instance.

Comment: The Views folder has a web.config as part of the default setup to overwrite certain settings, can another one be added to somewhere similar maybe such as controllers to override it maybe? I tried on that web.config itself but didn't overwrite it

Comment: @user no, the Views/Web.config is only for the Razor compiler. It doesn't override anything in any way.